# Merge list of list with duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates, reduce

Input list

```
[(1, 0, 3), '21:40:44', (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), '.273']
[(1, 0, 3), '21:43:37', (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), '.060']
[(1, 0, 3), '21:45:27', (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), '.410']
```

And the result should be like:

```
[(1, 0, 3), ['21:40:44', '21:43:37', '21:45:27'], (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), ['.273', '.060', '.410']
```

The goal is to reduce the duplicates, the unique elements in a column should be stored in a list.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

How about using zip. It will merge the 3 list and give you output with duplicates. later use set to remove duplicates. and since you don not want list of tuple for single element only, use `list(set(x))[0] if len(set(x))==1 else list(set(x))`

```
a=[(1, 0, 3), '21:40:44', (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), '.273']
b=[(1, 0, 3), '21:43:37', (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), '.060']
c=[(1, 0, 3), '21:45:27', (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), '.410']
l=[list(set(x))[0] if len(set(x))==1 else list(set(x)) for x in list(zip(a,b,c))]
print(l)
>>>[(1, 0, 3), ['21:45:27', '21:40:44', '21:43:37'], (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), ['.060', '.273', '.410']]
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is this:

```
in_data = [
[(1, 0, 3), '21:40:44', (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), '.273'],
[(1, 0, 3), '21:43:37', (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), '.060'],
[(1, 0, 3), '21:45:27', (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), '.410']
]
res = []
for i in range(len(in_data[0])):
    data = list(set([x[i] for x in in_data ]))
    data = data[0] if len(data) == 1 else data
    res.append(data)
print(res)
>>> [(1, 0, 3), ['21:43:37', '21:40:44', '21:45:27'], (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 6), ['.273', '.060', '.410']]
```